# smtpmail + protonmail bridge connectivity

Tags: smtpmail

I'm trying to send mail using smtpmail through the protonmail bridge app.
The protonmail-brdige runs a local smtp server with parameters:

- 127.0.0.1
- 1025
- email
- password
- STARTTLS

The snippet I have in my `smtpmail-multi-accounts`

```
(protonmail . ("email@protonmail.com"
                        "127.0.0.1"
                        1025
                        "email@protonmail.com"
                        starttls
                        nil nil nil)
```

When trying to send the mail I got a popup stating that the ssl certificat offered by the host didn't match the hostname, which makes sense.

But after this I only get the following errors:

```
Sending...
Sending via mail...
Trying protonmail account... 
502 5.7.0 anonymous login not supported
221 2.0.0 Goodnight and good luck
Failed to send mail via protonmail account
smtpmail-multi-send-it: Mail not sent
```

I thought that the problem may be ssl. for offlineimap I had disabled ssl and this worked for mail retrieval. But I can't figure it out for sending.

Is there a way to disable ssl in smtpmail?

Or is the problem something else entirely?

Also where did the state of the authentication get saved ? as in I'm no longer receiving the ssl warning, but I'd like to reset things so I can look closer.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: (info "(emacs) Network Security") describes that. Look in "~/.emacs.d/network-security.data"

Comment: Also: have you set up ".authinfo" or ".authinfo.gpg" with the username and password to use?

Comment: Hi, yeah I filled out .authinfo with ```machine 127.0.01 login email@protonmail.com port 1025 password ****```
But the error seems to say I'm trying to log in anonymously, which doesn't seem to be the case

Comment: Thanks for the network-security.data tip. I was able to reset the connection this way and get it to prompt me about the certificate. But after accepting the security exception I end up with the same mail not sent error.

Comment: Ah I just saw there was a typo in the hostname in .authinfo. That seemed to do the trick... thanks for the help

Comment: I have got the exact same issue. Haven't found much information about it. Support from ProtonMail hasn't been successful so far, but they are still investigating. Will let you know as the case may be.